# XSL syntax double dollar sign "$$"

Tags: xml, xslt

I have been walking through an xsl document and am not sure what the @domain$ne$ stands for.  Can you please help?

```
 <xsl:for-each select="./HEADER/META
                          [(./VALUE[not(text()='')]) and
                           (./@domain$ne$'PPPI_PROCESS_ORDER') and
                           (./@domain$ne$'PPPI_PROCESS_ORDER_TEXT') and
                           (./@domain$ne$'PPPI_MATERIAL') and 
                           (./@domain$ne$'PPPI_MATERIAL_SHORT_TEXT')]"
```

Comment: @user494111: That XPath expression should throw a syntax error.

Comment: This is not valid XPath syntax.

Comment: XML cannot have $ sign in element name or attribute name .. so the above mentioned xpath sounds meaningless. @User494111, the data that you have provided as information isn't sufficient.

Comment: @ infant programmer  The XSLT was designed by SAP as part of their PI module.  <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-xsl">        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, that is not valid XPath (or XSLT).

However in XPath 2.0 there is a `ne` operator, meaning "not equals". It's like `!=` but applies to single, atomic values instead of node sets (existential comparison).

It looks very likely that `ne` is what's intended, but the `$` signs should be replaced with spaces.

```
<xsl:for-each select="./HEADER/META
                      [(./VALUE[not(text()='')]) and
                       (./@domain ne 'PPPI_PROCESS_ORDER') and
                       (./@domain ne 'PPPI_PROCESS_ORDER_TEXT') and
                       (./@domain ne 'PPPI_MATERIAL') and 
                       (./@domain ne 'PPPI_MATERIAL_SHORT_TEXT')]">
```

I wonder what happened to it that the `ne`s got surrounded with `$`.

There are a few other things you could do to make the code less verbose, but that's not the focus of your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I was asked by a SAP developer to look at this transformation document.  I was leaning toward 'not equals' but didn't know what the purpose of the double $$ signs.

Comment: Just as a follow up, the code turned out to be pretty old and out of date.

Answer (score 0):

Have not found anything but $ is often used to represent a variable but in this case it looks lake a separator, ´like it @domain not equal to 'PPPI_PROCESS_ORDER' but I cannot find anything supporting this.

What kind of data is it matching or supposed to match.

Comment: That XPath expression should throw a syntax error. In XPath 1.0, the "not equal" operator is `!=`. But you should note that node set comparison are existencial comparison.

Comment: As I wrote, I cannot find any match to it, nut the ne suggested it might be some not equal operator. My thought was to test on the actual data in the actual situation to see if ne or eq gives different results or if both gives an error. Either way we would have more to go on  ;)

Answer (score 0):

**This is not syntactically valid XPath (and XSLT).**

Here's the reaction of one XSLT 1.0 processor (Saxon 6.5.4):

```
SAXON 6.5.4 from Michael Kay
Java version 1.6.0_21
Error at xsl:for-each on line 10 of file:/(Untitled):
  Error in expression ./HEADER/META                           [(./VALUE[not(text()='')]) and                            (./@domain$ne$'PPPI_PROCESS_ORDER') and                            (./@domain$ne$'PPPI_PROCESS_ORDER_TEXT') and                            (./@domain$ne$'PPPI_MATERIAL') and                            (./@domain$ne$'PPPI_MATERIAL_SHORT_TEXT')]: expected ")", found "$"
Transformation failed: Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected.
Press any key to continue . . .
```